# Why does function calling order affect borrows?

Tags: rust

Why do I need to force a scope of the borrows in this case? Without it, `k.keep("X")` will cause a compilation error.

```
mod keep {
    use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::{Occupied, Vacant};
    use std::collections::HashMap;
    use std::hash::Hash;

    pub struct Keeper<T> {
        index:  Vec<T>,
        kept:   HashMap<T, usize>
    }
    impl<T> Keeper<T> {
        pub fn new() -> Keeper<T> where T: Eq + Hash {
            Keeper { index: Vec::new(), kept: HashMap::new() }
        }
        pub fn keep(&mut self, keepsake: T) -> usize where T: Eq + Hash + Copy {
            match self.kept.entry(keepsake) {
                Occupied(_)   => (),
                Vacant(entry) => {
                    entry.insert(self.index.len());
                    self.index.push(keepsake);
                }
            }
            *self.kept.get(&keepsake).unwrap()
        }
        pub fn find(&self, i:usize) -> &T {
            &self.index[i]
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut k: keep::Keeper<&str> = keep::Keeper::new();
    { // forced borrow scoping
        let (k1, k2, k3) = (k.keep("A"), k.keep("A"), k.keep("B"));
        println!("{}@[{:p}], {}@[{:p}], {}@[{:p}]", k1, &k1, k2, &k2, k3, &k3);
        let (s1, s2, s3) = (k.find(k1), k.find(k2), k.find(k3));
        println!("{}@[{:p}], {}@[{:p}], {}@[{:p}]", s1, s1, s2, s2, s3, s3);
    }
    let k4 = k.keep("X");
}
```

There is [a playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2f3c4ba06a48d70b3801853185cc373d&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: For reference, here is the final keeper: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=273a79572157005e51cc3fff76919f78&version=stable&backtrace=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward case; in the following binding:

```
let (s1, s2, s3) = (k.find(k1), k.find(k2), k.find(k3));
```

You immutably borrow `k` 3 times (you can have multiple immutable borrows), so as long as `s1`, `s2` and `s3` are in the scope, you can not mutably borrow `k`.

By introducing your own scope you made `s1`, `s2` and `s3` release their borrows by the end of their block.

Comment: Would that likely lead to problems and Keeper should be redesigned, or is this expected behaviour and keepers will work fine in most situations as they are?

Comment: That depends on what you are going to do with the `Keeper`; in this case (printing purposes), it is perfectly fine to introduce an extra scope. Try to work around such cases for now and decide when you are more convinced about your API and its uses.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal reproduction:

```
struct Foo {
    something: i32,
}

impl Foo {
    fn give_something(&self) -> &i32 {
        &self.something
    }
    fn bar(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo{ something: 42, };
    // In the following line, you borrow self.something with thing,
    // therefore, foo is borrowed too:
    let thing = foo.give_something();
    // Then you cannot mutably borrow foo since it is already borrowed:
    foo.bar();
}
```

All is in the explanation of the compiler:

> cannot borrow `foo` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

You can either have **one mutable** reference on a thing, either have **multiple immutable** reference, not both.

Now see in your code: you borrow first `k` as immutable:

```
let (s1, s2, s3) = (k.find(k1), k.find(k2), k.find(k3));
```

And then you ask to borrow it as mutable:

```
let k4 = k.keep("X");
```

Comment: So, it is ok to go from mutable to immutable, since calling keep before find works, but not the other way around?

Comment: Nope, the rule is if you **own** a reference on a thing. `keep` returns no reference.

Comment: Ah, so since T is specified in keep as Copy, would it be better to return a Copy of T from find?

Comment: If you return a copy, do not worry about borrow checker since you borrow nothing from the struct.